# What is the Max() function?

Tags: c#

Consider:

```cs
var approve = UnitOfWork.Query.Lexis.ApprovedLexis2(DialogService.User.UserID, List.Where(x=>x.Check).Max(x=>x.TxnDate), _batch);
```

What does the line of code return?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.8 briefly explains the Max function. Does that help? Or do you really want to know about the whole line? You've asked two different questions, one in the title and one in the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
List.Where(x=>x.Check).Max(x=>x.TxnDate)
```

Presumably here `List` is a list/collection/some `IEnumerable<T>` for a type `T` that has (at least) a `bool` member named `Check`, and some other member `TxnDate` (presumably a `DateTime` of the transaction date).

The `Where` applies a predicate filter, i.e. it creates a filtered sequence of the items where `Check` is `true`. The `Max` finds the greatest (in terms of `x>y`, implemented by `IComparable[<T>]`) of the `.TxnDate` of each item in the filtered sequence.

So: the expression returns the greatest (last, timewise) transaction date of all the "checked" items in `List`. If there are no "checked" items, it will throw an exception (you can't ask for the largest of no values; or rather, you can ask, but you won't get a sensible answer).